# Jquery Mobile Slider Customization

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider, customization

[image]

what if i want to display the input box ABOVE the slider at the centre??

In the image provided, we can see that the input box is overlapping the slider & also the input box's top right & bottom right corner doesn't have border radius.

Is it possible to do these customization?

Demo:  `http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/572/`

i did this by doing

```
$(".ui-slider-input").wrap($('<div />').css({
    position : 'relative',
    display  : 'inline-block',
    height   : '36px',
    width    : '45px',
    overflow : 'hidden'
    top      : '2%',
    left     : '30%'

}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your Replies. 
Actually I wanted to get rid of those up-down arrows from the text box. Finally found the solution.

I just hid the text box that comes along with the slider, & inserted a new text box whose value changes as we move the slider.

```
<input id="txtvalBox" type="text" value="" />

$("#points").change(function () {

    document.getElementById("txtvalBox").value = document.getElementById("points").value;
});

//points is the id of the slider
```

See This
http:http://jsfiddle.net/Gk_999/mxzu5Ld3/

Comment: Get rid of that long line of code and add this js (number = number($(this).val());) -- make sure you initialize the variable prior to the function (var number = "default number";)

Answer (score 1):

The top (top : '2%') dosent like percentages so use pixels. Also the height and width had a problem that's why the border was not there. My screen is wide and the box is centered so adjust the (left : '46%') percentage to get it centered if its not.

I did a Demo for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/k7XAj/4/

**Code**

```
$(".ui-slider-input").wrap($('<div />').css({
    position : 'relative',
    display  : 'inline-block',
    height   : '40px',
    width    : '70px',
    overflow : 'hidden',
    top      : '-30px',  
    left     : '46%'
}));
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see those on the box, but to get rid of them adjust (height : '40px') to something like 45px or 50px; or greater until they go away.

Comment: oK I See the arrows when i hover on the box. That's something in built to JQM 1.1 and browsers like chrome. Im not sure how to get rid of them. You dont see those arrows in later versions of JQM.

Comment: Exactly, when i tried the same using JQM 1.4.3, i could get the output i wanted. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Wraping input element and slider will get you better results in different browser sizes

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/574/

```
$(".ui-slider-input").each(function(){

    $(this).css({
        position  : 'absolute',
        top      : '2%',
        left     : '30%',
        marginLeft: '-10px'
    })

     .add($(this).next()).wrapAll($('<div />').css({
        position : 'relative',
        paddingTop: '40px'
    }))
 });
```

Comment: thnx for ur reply....Actually I wanted to get rid of the up-down arrows from the text box. Check my answer